# Do simple LED strip dimmers consume power while turned off?

Tags: led-strip, power-consumption

I am referring to this kind of LED strip dimmers:

[image: Remote LED strip dimmer]

I want to know if it consumes power while the LED strip is off, and if so, how much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they will. It may be a few milliamps, or even less, in the microamp range, but they will as the microcontroller and passives are still powered even when the microcontroller is asleep or simply has it's PWM timers off. **Since it is an RF accessible controller, it will need power for it's radio receiver interface.**

The only way to get to 0 power is a physical switch. And the power supply would still be connected, so a physical switch on the power supply's AC side as well.

As to exactly how much power, get a multimeter and test it. It won't be much.

Comment: Is it possible that these dimmers or the equivalent physical switch dimmers consume the full power when turned off, or is it always negligible? Also, when dimming to 50%, does it consume the full power or half?

Comment: @amiregelz I'd presume it would consume more than half since there is the circuit that would be doing the PWM.

Comment: @amiregelz these dimmers don't take much power by themselves. The led strips you add to it will dwarf it. But if you are asking if your normally 1 Amp Led Strip will take only 0.5 Amps at 50% dimming, then yes.